# GA4 Funnel Query

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

We are trying to build a query to visualize a GA4-funnel (Website Funnel). A funnel can look like this, for example:

1. Homepage
2. Product Page
3. Add to Cart
4. Purchase

We want to count the users for every funnel-step. So we can calculate how many people get through the whole funnel and how many people leave the website after certain steps.

What makes it complex is that the steps doesn’t have to follow each other directly. So a possible “correct” funnel can be:

1. Homepage
2. Category Page
3. Product Page
4. Add to Cart
5. Purchase.

I was thinking about a string_agg of the different steps, followed by an REGEX to check if it matches the funnel and Index to make sure the steps are in the right order. So you get something like this:

| User ID | Funnel Steps (STRING_AGG) | Step 1 | Step 2 | Step 3 | Step 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Homepage > Category Page > Product Page > Add to Cart > Purchase | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE |
| 2 | Homepage > Product Page > Add to Cart > Purchase | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE |
| 3 | Product Page > Add to Cart > Purchase | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| 4 | Homepage > Category > Add to Cart > Purchase | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| 5 | Product Page > Homepage > Add to Cart > Product Page | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |

Anyone know a efficient/better way the query this?

Thanks a lot!